# How to get values from the first column of jTable and store it in a database?

Tags: java, swing, sqlite, netbeans

Hey I don't know how to a the value from jTablePM ( but just first values in the first column) . After that I would like to insert them to the database. All I want to do is to just get songID from jTablePM and write it to database.
Can someone help me ?

Sorry for the messiness..

```
private void jButton38MouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        

    String playlistname;
    int playlistNum = 0;
    try{

        pst = conn.createStatement();
        rs = pst.executeQuery("select max(playlist_id) from playlist;");

        while (rs.next()) {
            playlistNum = rs.getInt(1);
        }
        playlistNum += 1;

        String userID = jLabel1.getText();
        pst = conn.createStatement();
        playlistname = jTextField2.getText();
        String addPlaylist = "INSERT INTO playlist (playlist_id, userID, playlist_name, songID)" + "VALUES('"+ playlistNum + "', '" + userID + "','" + playlistname + "', 'songID');" ;
        pst.executeUpdate(addPlaylist);
        conn.close();
        //rs.close();
        //pst.close();

    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

And the code with jTable data:

```
private void jMenuItem1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    PlaylistMaker frame3 = new PlaylistMaker(); // Frames changing
    AddToPlaylist.this.setVisible(false);
    frame3.setVisible(true);

    TableModel model1 = jTable1.getModel();

    int[] index = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    Object[] row = new Object[5];
    DefaultTableModel model2 = (DefaultTableModel) frame3.jTablePM.getModel();

    for(int i = 0; i < index.length; i++) {

        row[0] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 0);
        row[1] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 1);
        row[2] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 2);
        row[3] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 3);
        row[4] = model1.getValueAt(index[i], 4);

        model2.addRow(row);
    }
```

Comment: jButton has better Listener - ActionListener

Comment: So your `jMenuItem1ActionPerformed` seems to have the basic idea, what is the problem you're actually having?